# QGIS Georeferencer; CRS selector doesn't open, destination coords 0

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, georeferencing

I've tried this in QGIS 2.14 LTR, 2.16 and 2.18, and a fresh install of 2.14 LTR on another PC.

My questions are:

1. **How do I get the CRS selector dialog to open?** When opening a raster image, I get no CRS selector dialog, as [these](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/georeferencing_basics.html) two [guides](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/map_georeferencing.html) clearly show it should. Instead I get an internal error message "*CRS was undefined: defaulting to project CRS*". I can select the right CRS from the project properties, but the second issue is unchanged.
2. **How do I make the georeferencer output destination coordinates?** When adding control points in the Georeferencer, their coordinates just show *0.00*. Predictably, the image will fail transformation.
   [image]

Comment: Please [edit] your Question to contain a question.

Comment: Try `Settings -> Options -> CRS -> CRS for new Layers` set to `Prompt for CRS`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer my own questions;

1. **How to get the CRS selector dialog to open?** `Settings -> Options -> CRS -> CRS for new Layers -> Prompt for CRS.` Thanks to [AndreJ](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/266596/qgis-georeferencer-crs-selector-doesnt-open-destination-coords-0#comment423452_266596) for the solution.
2. **How to make the georeferencer output destination coordinates?** The [map provider](https://asiointi.maanmittauslaitos.fi/karttapaikka/)—which can convert the old KKJ Finland coordinates to newer coordinate systems—outputs coordinates as `xxxxxxx,000`. Apparently the decimal mark should have been a point, not a comma.